# Cannot access org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactory Method setVelocityEngine()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, velocity, spring-context

i have upgraded my java web project from spring boot 1.5.22 to 2.6.6. During this Upgrade the Velocity package is not even deprecated, it got removed. I know that it is recommended to switch to FreeMarker, but as a quick fix i was trying to fix my project.
First i included the following three dependencies to get the old velocity package and classes.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.25.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

After this most of my code got fixed after some changes.
The last remaining problem in my configuration bean is my VelocityConfigurer. I am trying to init a VelocityEngine with some properties and to create a VelocityConfigurer with the freshly created VelocityEngine afterwards. Like i did it before the spring boot update.

```
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeConstants;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

@Bean
@Primary
public VelocityConfigurer velocityEngineBean() {

    VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
    engine.setProperty(Velocity.RESOURCE_LOADER, "ds");
    engine.setProperty("ds.resource.loader.class", "XXX.CustomDataResourceLoader");

    engine.setProperty("spring.velocity.checkTemplateLocation=false", "false");
    engine.setProperty("spring.velocity.velocimacro.library", "XXX.vm");

    engine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, Slf4jLogChute.class.getName());

    engine.init();

    VelocityConfigurer velocityConfigurer = new VelocityConfigurer();
    velocityConfigurer.setVelocityEngine(engine);
    return velocityConfigurer;
}
```

}

But i get the following error. [Error: Cannot access org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip3S8.png)

I can figure out why it can access this method.
The .jar with the Class is there.[VelocityEngineFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8MW8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won’t work as Spring Boot 2.6 requires Spring Framework 5.3. Velocity support was [deprecated in Spring Framework 4.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17826) and removed in 5.0. If you want to use an up-to-date and supported version of Spring Boot (2.5.x or 2.6.x at the time of writing), you should migrate to an alternative templating engine.

Comment: but can’t I import the required velocity dependency in the specific version?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is no support for Velocity in a version of Spring Framework that is compatible with Spring Boot 2.x.